# Uploading play application to maven repository

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am trying to upload a play 2.1.3 application to our internal maven repository. I would like the zip file generated by `play dist` to be uploaded to the repo.

I tried following the steps mentioned in the [this Google group thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/BoWw65F6vg8/0MYYEv4qUy4J) <del>but the method `dependsOn` does not seem to exist on `TaskKey` anymore!.</del> but with no luck; `publish` continues to publish only the jar file.

How can I make sure the the artifact published by the `publish` task is the zip file generated by `dist`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [sbt-aether-deploy](https://github.com/arktekk/sbt-aether-deploy) sbt plugin to deploy the play application to the nexus repository.